# How can I select some elements from div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I set values of some elements for e.g I have 9 div and I want to access some of those div using jquery.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
 <div>7</div>
 <div>8</div>
```

I want to loop through some part of div to give it a styling.

```
 var divs = $('div');

 for (var x= 3; x < divs.length; x++) {
         divs[x].css("color", "blue");
 }
```

But this gives me an error. Any ideas on how I can access it?

Thank you.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 2):

Please see my code. I'm adding Code Snippet. I clicked button "Style Div" to change color of alternate div's.

```js
 function styleDiv()
    {
        var divLength = $(".MainDiv div");
        for (var i = 1; i < divLength.length; i+=2)
        {
            $(divLength[i]).css("color", "blue");
        }

    }
```

```css
.styleButton
{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="styleButton">
    <input onclick="styleDiv()" type="button" value="Style Div" />
</div>

<div class="MainDiv">
    <div>1 div</div>
    <div>2 div</div>
    <div>3 div</div>
    <div>4 div</div>
    <div>5 div</div>
    <div>6 div</div>
    <div>7 div</div>
    <div>8 div</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```js
$('div:lt(3)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var divs = $('div');
    for(var x= 3; x < divs.length; x++){
         $(divs[x]).css("color", "blue");
     }
```

In your example divs[x] was not an jquery object so it raised error. Convert it to jquery object `$(divs[x])`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution without jquery.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
var r = 5;
var g = 10;
var b = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b +")";
  r += 30;
  g += 50;
  b += 70;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
```

I know your tag says jquery but I would like to show to you that you can use pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
$("div").each(function(){
    if (count>3) {
        $(this).css("color","red");
    }
    count++;
});
```